# Exporting a model to be read by Assimp

Tags: texturing, uv, export, normals

I'm trying to create some low-poly models for my game and I'm trying to learn some Blender basics. I can create a model and export it to Wavefront or Collada and I'm able to import it into my code using Assimp. What I cannot do though, is to export normals and UV coordinates ALONG with some information about the texture used in Blender (diffuse map and posibly specular map for now) so I can use them with my shaders.

I created a simple cube and unwrapped it, I exported the uv layout and in photoshop I added some colors:

[image]

Now I don't know what to do. I just need UV coordinates, normals AND textures (a reference in the exported .obj model or .mat file for example) that lets Assimp find material indices nto the mesh with which load the texture file.

I tested my code with some free models on the web and it all works like a charm:

[image]

Comment: Collada file format does support UVs, normals as well as texture packing, why are you not able to use the feature?

Comment: @kheetor I'm a total noob at Blender